# Capybara not triggering Simplecov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara to create some integration tests for creating a product in my project.  Despite working, Simplecov doesn't seem to pick up on it being tested.  Here's the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Product creation' do
    scenario 'user logged in as admin' do
        create_logged_in_admin

        visit new_product_path

        fill_in 'Name' , :with => "Test Product"
        fill_in 'Domain' , :with => "test.com"

        click_button "Create Product"

        page.should have_content 'Product was successfully created'
    end
end
```

However the products controller does not show up as being tested with the create method.  any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Very difficult to tell. Does SimpleCov work with your unit tests? Do they use the same `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig, I don't use test unit specifically, but yes, it does work with my other rspec tests (on models, etc).

Comment: Does this test pass? There may be case that some error occurs during the execution of line `create_logged_in_admin` and the test does not proceed.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  It was a really crazy bug, in which the error page was displaying the text I was looking for.  Hence it was passing, despite the page being broken :/